# Ionic Status bar color in splash screen

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i'm working on a simple app with ionic 3, the app is working but i have a problem with the status bar during the splash screen, it's black and i'd like to change the color to the same blue of the splash screen

[image]

i tried with the Ionic Native - Splash Screen, it changes the color of the status bar, but after the splash screen

[image]

here's the code

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {


      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#002e5b');
      this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    });
  }
```

is there any way to achieve this? thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. And I fixed it with a fork:

https://github.com/goinnn/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tree/4.0.0%23colors

Installing this fork:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/goinnn/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git#4.0.0#colors
```

If you get this error:

```
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
```

Another time (it is very crazy):

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/goinnn/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git#4.0.0#colors
```

In your config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#YOUR_COLOR" />
    <preference name="SplashNavigationBarBackgroundColor" value="#YOUR_COLOR" />
```

[image: Add a screenshot]

Comment: i tried, it didn't make any difference, still black the status bar

Comment: Are you sure you are using the "4.0.0#colors" branch? It works for me perfect.

Comment: <preference name="SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#002e5b" /> and 
        <preference name="SplashNavigationBarBackgroundColor" value="#002e5b" /> did i set them wrong??

Comment: I think your are not using my fork. It is work for me.

Comment: I am also unable to get this to work, using your fork. Can your provide install instructions?

Comment: @TerPro done! I edited my answer. It is very easy :-)

Comment: I'm sorry I had a typo error in the git URL. I edited my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for detailed instructions!

Comment: @bene-we Thanks! But it is only development, nothing about charm :-p

Answer (score 0):

`Splash screen` is showing while the platform is loading.
When platform is ready, status bar color will be `#002e5b`.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
  this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#002e5b');
  this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
});
```

I think there is no way to access `platform` before this method `this.platform.ready()`.

Comment: so, there's no way to change the color??

Comment: No. U can change status bar color when platform is ready and that's it.

Comment: That's it... if you don't change the cordova-plugin-splashscreen plugin. Almost never "that is it" developing

Comment: @HéctorPérezSilva Follow instructions from Goin answer and tell us how/does it works. Thanks for solution.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I had a typo error in the git URL. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have splash with a single color as background, change status bar color to same.

For Android, add following in `styles.xml` (I'm showing status bar with white background)

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the correct way but I did not find another way.

This is what I did:

1-I removed the "splash screen" plugin and added it again, but this time this fork.

ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/goinnn/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git#4.0.0#colors

2- Then in this path: platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen.java

Change these lines of code:

```
 // Inspirated in https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/pull/124/files
            String statusBarColor = preferences.getString("SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor", "#000000");

            if (statusBarColor != null && !statusBarColor.isEmpty() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

                splashWindow.clearFlags(0x04000000);
                splashWindow.addFlags(0x80000000);
                try {
                    // Using reflection makes sure any 5.0+ device will work without having to compile with SDK level 21
                    splashWindow.getClass().getMethod("setStatusBarColor", int.class).invoke(splashWindow, Color.parseColor(statusBarColor));
                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                    // this should not happen, only in case Android removes this method in a version > 21
                    LOG.w("SplashScreen StatusBarColor", "Method window.setStatusBarColor not found for SDK level " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                }
            }
```

3-In the config.xml file you add this preference:

```
<preference name="SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#50ABC5" />
```

And yeah, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists and I tried to find where the black bars are coming from.

a. in the file splashscreen.java the defaut theme android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar is loaded to build the dialogue and this of course overwrites everything that you have set up before. I solved it to overwrite this file to access my own module style.

```
            // Create and show the dialog
            splashDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).